# Unreliable Google Docs copy-paste in Safari

Tags: google-drive, copy-paste, safari-5

I'm using Safari and copy-pasting in Google Docs with a keyboard shortcut is extremely unreliable. It can work most of the time, but at some point the Cut and Copy items in the Safari menu become disabled and the only way to get copy-paste working again is to reload the page.

Is there any way of getting copy-paste to work properly in other browsers, or is using Google Chrome the only solution, as described in this topic: 
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40147/in-copy-paste-google-docs-says-these-actions-are-unavailable-via-the-edit-menu

Answer (score 1):

I’ve found that rather than reloading the entire document, simply changing it in any way (e.g. entering a space somewhere) re-jiggers it so that copy will work again…

Until it doesn't (usually one time), and you get the “beep” and then you have to type something again.

Annoying, but far less annoying than reloading the entire doc each time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the content in the url bar of Safari and then copy it again from then.

After that you can paste it in the Google Docs document.

Answer (score 0):

For literally *years* I have been unable to make copy/paste operations work in Google Docs in Safari. Attempting to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> would cause a beep and not produce any other action; attempting to use the Edit menu commands would always result in this dialog box being shown:

[image]

**Today, I discovered a solution**: I used the "Remove All Website Data" button in Safari under the *Preferences* ➜ *Privacy tab*:

[image]

After this, I had to log back into Google to access documents, but since then, copy/cut/paste has been working for me in the same documents where the operations did not work earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix pasting without formatting in google docs on safari (2021):

1. Go to System Preferences - Keyboard - Apps - And then Click the + button and choose safari.
2. Enter in the command section the following text: paste and match style
3. Put the shortcut command shift v.

Click the image for a detailed walk through:
[image: click on it]

This basically happens because google docs and safari shortcuts are clashing, if you change the safari shortcut, it works. This is because you can't change google doc shortcuts.